# Simplest way to access media files on Android using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cors, local-files

I need to access files in a Cordova app targeting Android. I need to be able to do it by passing a URI (e.g. "file://..." or "https://...") because that's the format I need to pass an API that will open the files ([Howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/) to play .mp3 files).

This seems to rule out `cordova-plugin-file`, as far as I understand it. I have tried both hosting locally and remotely. I have tried installing cordova-plugin-whitelist. My config.xml contains

`<access origin="*"/> <allow-navigation href="*"/>` and my html contains `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:"/>`.

I'm thus covering as many bases as I can find mentioned in any documentation, but no joy - permission to access the files is always denied. Suggestions much appreciated.

EDIT -------------------

In response to Eric below I have tried editing my config.xml and it is now as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>HelloCordova</name>
  <description>&#xD;
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.&#xD;
    </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">&#xD;
        Apache Cordova Team&#xD;
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
  <!-- <hook src="node_modules/cordova-import-npm/scripts/importNpmPackages.js" type="before_prepare"/> -->
</widget>
```

However my build now crashes with an error message visible [here](https://pastebin.com/sCJ48vsn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add

```
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

to your config.xml, most probably a CORS issue.

Comment: Thanks. Still just not enough to make it work. Getting "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/assets/myfile" when I try local or "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/myfile' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." when I try remote.

Comment: Shouldn't ben since you're bypassing CORS here. Paste your config in your post pls

Comment: Thanks, have now added my config.xml. I have a strange situation where adding the AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled makes it now crash on build (https://pastebin.com/sCJ48vsn), however this crash is a bit unreliable and apparently didn't happen the first time I added the line. Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: Try putting the preference out of the Android node, put it at root level of config.xml

Comment: Seeing as I couldn't find any documentation anyway explaining how it's supposed to work, I had already tried both. It has the same result - either crashes the build, or does nothing, according to no logic I can fathom. Maybe I should try upgrading my Android platform to version 10 - I'm using 9.

Comment: Yes, this parameter only works for cordova-android 10+

Comment: Thanks @Eric - I finally have a better understanding of this. I upgraded to cordova-android 10 and it still didn't work, but finally I realised the reason it didn't work was that I was using cordova-plugin-ionic-webview which appears to prevent AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled from working. Removing that plugin makes file access work with the insecure mode. The problem is I need that plugin because otherwise javascript modules don't work. Or more precisely, without it, modules work on some phones but not others. If anyone knows a way I can access files and also use js modules, I'd love to know.