Cordova-based app: How to play an audio file from Android Internal storage/Music folder
Version information:
cordova version 12.0.0
cordova-media-plugin version 7.0.0
cordova-plugin-file version 8.1.0
cordova-plugin-file-transfer version 2.0.0
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr version 3.1.1
Android Target SDK = 34
Problem/Question:
I am struggling with getting a Cordova-based app to play a file that is downloaded to the "Internal storage/Music" location of an Android device. The downloadAudio function below works properly to save the file there (though the file plugin documentation states this location is the SD card, that is not how it works on my device).

Can the media plugin play from the location "file:///storage/emulated/0/Music/[file].mp3"? It would appear that I need a cdvfile reference for the media plugin, but I'm not sure if "cdvfile://" format works with this external location either. It would seem it is for internal-to-app use only?

EDIT: I get an error that the file cannot be found if I reference a bogus location, so in the absence of that error, it would seem that the Media plugin can see the file. However, after removing a syntax error, the Media plugin produces an error "Code 1, Prepare failed.: status=0x1". This link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761305/android-mediaplayer-throwing-prepare-failed-status-0x1-on-2-1-works-on-2-2] seems related but confuses me... need to understand it better.

I cannot get any of the URL conversion methods (e.g. toURL gives me TypeError: fileTransferInternalUrl.toURL is not a function) to work with my file location without returning an error in order to generate a cdvfile URL for the media plugin.

EDIT: It would seem that my file URL might be working even though toURL doesn't.

If the media plugin doesn't support play referencing an external-to-app location, is it possible to use copyTo (and overwrite existing file) from the external location to a temporary internal location which is accessible to the media plugin? (The copyTo documentation seems to be missing from later versions of the file plugin documentation, and I run into errors using that also. More specifics can be given if it is said to be possible.

Copying a file using Cordova
did not work for me, nor the example at
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova/file/fileentry/fileentry.html.
I am not getting any errors related to permissions. I don't think the download would work if it was a permissions issue(?) I know there were changes to the Android permissions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Update/Edit 10/8/24:
I updated code per Eric's code suggestion for toURL, which does return a URL. However, this gives me these errors, which seem to indicate Media player can't use this URL?
Media player error: Code 1, AudioPlayer.onError(1, -2147483648) [unknown error]
Console error:
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:443
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.seekTo(MediaHTTPConnection.java:306)
at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.getMIMEType(MediaHTTPConnection.java:499)
at android.media.IMediaHTTPConnection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaHTTPConnection.java:161)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1220)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1179)

function downloadAudio (fileTransferWebUrl,thisElement) {
    fileTransferWebUrl = encodeURI(fileTransferWebUrl);
    if (isAndroidApp == true) {
        var fileNameMP3Array = fileTransferWebUrl.split("/");
        var fileNameMP3 = fileNameMP3Array[fileNameMP3Array.length-1]; //get file name from web URL
        fileTransferInternalUrl = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Music/' + fileNameMP3; //  file:///storage/emulated/0/Music/[file].mp3
    }
    try {
        fileTransfer.download(
            fileTransferWebUrl, 
            fileTransferInternalUrl, 
            function (entry) {
                alert('Download complete to Music/' + fileNameMP3);
            },
            function(error){ //error
                alert("Download error source " + error.source + " download error target " + error.target + " download error code " + error.code + " http_status " + error.http_status + " body " + error.body + " exception " + error.exception);
            },
            true, //trust all hosts. safer to be false, set to true accepts all security certificates, not recommended for production use
        );
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

function playDownloadedAudio (fileTransferWebUrl, thisElement) {
    var nativePath = "";
    fileTransferWebUrl = encodeURI(fileTransferWebUrl);
    if (isAndroidApp == true) {
        var fileNameMP3Array = fileTransferWebUrl.split("/");
        var fileNameMP3 = fileNameMP3Array[fileNameMP3Array.length-1]; //get file name from web URL
        fileTransferInternalUrl = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Music/' + fileNameMP3; //cordova.file.externalRootDirectory
        alert(fileTransferInternalUrl); // file:///storage/emulated/0/Music/A_casa_vete_y_cuenta_alli.mp3
    }
    resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileNameMP3, function (entry) {
        nativePath = entry.toURL(); 
        console.log("cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileNameMP3 = " + cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileNameMP3 + " | nativePath = " + nativePath);
        if (my_media != null) { 
            my_media.release(); // clean up old file
        }
        my_media = new Media(nativePath,
            function () //success;
            { }, 
            function (error) //error
            { 
                alertOK(translate('Error in playback. Please contact support. \n Code: ','text') + error.code + '\n '+translate('Message:','text')+' '+error.message + '\n');
                playing = false;
            }
        );
        my_media.play();
    });
}

My AndroidManifest.xml has the following currently:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

Config.xml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.hablamedecristo.himnario2" version="6.9.0" versionCode="77" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Himnos del Evangelio</name>
    <description>
        Himnario "Himnos del Evangelio" de cristianos congregados en el Nombre del Señor Jesucristo en Venezuela.
    </description>
    <author email="himnosdelevangelio@gmail.com" href="http://salvoxgracia.com/himnarioapp/">
        My Site Creations, AguaDeLaVida.info
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="preferExternal" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" /> <!-- use "Internal" instead of "Compatibility" for new apps -->
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="34" />
    <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="34" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
    <preference name="AndroidGradlePluginVersion" value="8.5.1" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="7.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-insomnia" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" spec="3.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="file:///*" />
    <access origin="cdvfile://*" />
    <allow-intent href="file:///*" />
    <allow-intent href="cdvfile://*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- not sure if these are needed  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#kotlin
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    -->
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <!-- <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/screen/android/splashscreen.xml" /> -->
        <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenBackground" value="#9D9D9C" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>


file system has changed a lot since version 2.4.0 (from the link of the documentation you mentioned). Updated version is https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

Also note that with the latest version of Cordova, cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr is obsolete

Based on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800233/simplest-way-to-access-media-files-on-android-using-cordova] it may not be possible to do this with wkwebview?

WKWebView is the webview by default now, there is no UIWebView anymore, so the plugin is deprecated.

The cdv:// protocol is not supported anymore on Android, see
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#cdvfile-protocol
Now for emulated storage, check the update note at
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#upgrading-notes
So to target the file, you should use the following, to obtain the correct URL for your file
resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Music/' + fileNameMP3, (entry) => {    
     var nativePath = entry.toURL();    
     //use nativePath  
});

Now here's the quirk for Android about that location :

With the introduction of Scoped Storage access to External Storage is
unreliable or limited via File APIs. Scoped Storage was introduced in
API 29. While existing apps may have the ability to opt out, this
option is not available for new apps. On Android API 30 and later,
Scoped Storage is fully enforced.
Additionally, Direct File Access is not supported on API 29. This
means this plugin cannot access external storage mediums on API 29
devices.

See https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file?tab=readme-ov-file#androids-external-storage-quirks
So you should consider a plugin that has access to external storage such as https://github.com/makiwin/cordova-plugin-saf-mediastore or download the files in the cordova.file.dataDirectory folder.
Please spend a bit more time reading the documentation, all the answers I've provided come from the documentation.

The update note states "It is recommended to always use the toURL() to ensure that the correct URL is returned." but that method isn't recognized for some reason?

I was confused by the note that cdv is not supported by Android, since that was the example for use with the media plugin which works with Android. Am I only able to access internal resources with the Media plugin it seems?

Not good news about the wkwebview plugin. That could mean a lot of rework...  I will have to look into workarounds :(

See updated response about nativePath

Thank you for the info on how to get nativePath -- that does work. However, the resulting URL does not work in the Media plugin and returns an error, per the update in my question...  I'm not sure if https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/613 is related or not... is it impossible to use the Media plugin to pull any file I download? I did not test all of the Android file location save options again with toURL.

The error shows that it's not able to connect to localhost. Paste your config.xml, I'm pretty sure you're missing some flags or preferences

I've added config.xml to my entry. That would be great if you could locate what I'm missing.

Not quite sure at this point, try to add 

Also try to add 

Unfortunately I still get the same error after those two additions. (The other, but less desirable, option would be if there were a way to download the file into the www folder so the media plugin could play it as it would if I added mp3 files to the build.)

I think you need all audio permissions, you've commented them in your config.xml

Considering the "Failed to connect to localhost" error, I would open a ticket at the plugin's github repo. Also, you know that you can play a mp3 file from the webview? You don't need to use a native layer to play a song ....

Same error with added permissions. The media plugin plays online files, but I just checked and it no longer plays a URL like "https://localhost/test.mp3" like it used to... so something changed and I'm not sure what. Maybe relates to the change in Android permissions?

I've updated my answer with what I believe is the proper path. Not sure why you did not reuse that path? Also that path is not available anymore. You need to download files in a different folder.

Regarding your comment about reading the documentation, I try, but it's confusing. For example, we are talking about external storage which  [https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage] says corresponds to things external to the device, but actually there is emulated external storage which is actually internal but only for certain APIs, and also there are multiple types of external storage which are distinguished from SD card so are they instead external to the application (& can we can access any of these locations except externalRootDirectory w/o the app)?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
